# How to convert NaN to 'N/A' in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

How should I convert NaN to N/A in Pandas?

Any thoughts and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: df=df.fillna('N/A')

Comment: I'd argue you *should not*.  It is much more flexible to leaving NaN values as NaN (such as not casting float columns to dtype 'object').  Is there a reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should clarify why you want to convert NaN to 'N/A'. NaN is a special internal representation of missing data. Sure 'N/A' represents missing data, but to python, this will just be another string, and will be decidedly different from a None/null/missing value.

Without clarification, I am assuming that you want to export NaN values as 'N/A' when you are writing a CSV, XL, etc...; in order to do that, you can use the na_rep argument

```
df.to_csv('path/to/my.csv', na_rep='N/A')
```

This will make NaN values in your exported file write out as 'N/A'.

---

pandas also has a fillna function, but be aware, this will convert missing data into a string, e.g.,

```
df.fillna('N/A')
```

will now not have any missing data, and pd.isna() will not work, since a String 'N/A' is not a null entry